# In package.json "scripts" section, do I need to prepend "npx" for some command that are supposed to use the executables in node_modules?

Tags: node.js, package.json

For example, if I have `tsc` available both system-wide and in `node_modules/`, and I would like the project to use the one in `node_modules/`, do I need to prepend `npx` before `tsc` in the `scripts` section in `package.json` like the follows?

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "prepack": "npx tsc"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in this case, you don't necessarily need to use `npx` before `tsc` in your scripts section. The reason is that npm will automatically look for locally installed packages in the `node_modules/.bin` directory when running scripts.

If `tsc` is installed locally in `node_modules`, npm will find and use that version automatically without needing `npx`. If it's not found locally, npm will then look for a global installation of `tsc`. This behavior is by design to ensure that scripts use the version of the command-line tools that are specified in your project's dependencies.

So, your script in the `package.json` can simply be:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "prepack": "tsc"
  }
}
```

This assumes that `tsc` is listed as a dependency in your `package.json` file or is installed locally in `node_modules`. If it's not, you might want to install it locally using:

```
npm install --save-dev typescript
```

This ensures that the correct version of TypeScript is used for your project.

Comment: Could you also give a reference?